# CSS: :focus:before doesn't work

Tags: css

I have a Slidemenu within a Sidemenu, when i'm clicking on a text label, some content shows up. `:before` the text label, i'm having some Arrows, that i want to rotate 90deg, when clicked.

Code:

```
li.textClass:focus:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
}
```

if i change `:focus` to `:active`  it works untill i release the left mouse button, but it should stay rotated.... how do i fix this? i can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a little more detail of what you are trying to do?  Maybe an example of your html block?

For an `li` element, you should not use focus (that would be better for inputs & textareas) - I would use hover.

See full example in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wexwnc9b/

**HTML:**

```
    <ul>
      <li class="textClass">TextClass</li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
    li.textClass {
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0 30px;
    }

    li.textClass::before {
      content: 'X';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }

    li.textClass:hover::before {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
```

Comment: well its basically what you've done here. but i want the arrow to stay rotated, not only on `:hover` or on `:active`